# I don't see Google DataStore API usage statistics after upgrading from API v1beta2 to v1beta3

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-console

I used to watch API usage in either API section of Google cloud console or AppEngine section. But since moving from v1beta2 to v1beta3 of API I don't observer any charts there. It looks like no traffic while in fact there is.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-datastore/issues/133.

You can see daily usage in the App Engine section, but it doesn't show live request rates.

Comment: This is my ticket Ed